# A file or folder with the name already exists Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I try to add a new file to my source controlled solution and receive this message:

> A file or folder with the name 'xxx' already exists. Please give a unique
> name to the item you are adding, or delete the existing item first.

I'm 100% sure that there is no file with the given name.

So how do I get VS to add items again?

Comment: What do you try to add? Did you check in your folder if there is not a hidden file?

Comment: Did you activate "Show All files" in Solution Explorer? Maybe there are some kind of "Phantom Files". Did you check project file if there is some kind of strange entry?

Comment: @glautrou Any file I want to add will fail, be it a CS file or a HTML file, javascript file, nothing works

Comment: @Micha, There are no hidden folders or files... that's the weird thing about it, also what do you mean by 'strange entry' ?

Comment: If you cannot add any file and the problem occurs since the update, try to rollback Visual Studio update, if you cannot reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: @Ruudt this is the question :-). Did you have the problem in every VS-Solution or only in special project?

Comment: @Micha I have a MVC solution that is TFS source controlled, which exposes the error. My other winforms application does not suffer from the same problems

Comment: @Micha alright! rolling back seemed to did the trick :-). Maybe you can post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Here The comment as Answer.
Did you have the problem in every VS-Solution or only in special project? Rollback helps :-)

Comment: Here The comment as Answer.
Did you have the problem in every VS-Solution or only in special project? Rollback helps :-)

Comment: I had the same problem. I thought it was a TFS issue or Windows AD problem. I installed Visual Studio Update 4 which failed due to Application Certification Kit. I downloaded that separately and installed. Then I installed Visual Studio Update 4. To my surprise, the error has stopped occurring.

Comment: To anyone building entities in D365, might be worth a mention that you will have to delete the XML files found in K:\AosService\PackagesLocalDirectory\ that correspond to the files it says already exists (that's not showing up in the solution explorer)

Answer (score 110):

Restarting Visual Studio didn't help, the folder is cached on the system.

Open `Solution Explorer` there is an icon that looks like a many Pages: [image: Show All Files] which is the `Show All Files`. Once clicked, one is able to see the hidden, to the visual studio project, the folder that was causing this error. (Look for the folder in the View section.)

After I deleted the unwanted folder, and Rebuild Project, You should be able to Create the controller which will create the view automatically...

Comment: I didn't delete the folder, but instead just added it to the project. Still marking this as a up vote since it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 22):

Restarting Visual Studio helped me.

Answer (score 17):

**Steps if a folder is Missing**

1. In the `Solution Explorer` **window**

   - Select visual studio project which holds the missing folder.
   - Select or turn on the `Show All Files` **button** ( [image: Show All Files] ) to show the existing, but missing folder.
2. Select the hidden folder then right click and select the menu item `Include in Project` to add into the project in the project view.

Comment: For those wondering where you turn this on: there is a button at the top of the Solution Explorer that looks like three files grouped together.

Comment: Thanks a lot Much Appreciated.

Answer (score 13):

Simply, On Solution Explorer Right CLick on Project's name -> Unload Project.
then right click on the same project and click 'Reload'.

Problem is Fixed (y)

Answer (score 10):

If you're using MVC, and trying to create a new Controller, you should also check the Views and Models. Even though there was no folder or file with the Controller name, I had to delete a View folder with the same name (that already existed for some reason) using `Show All Files` and rebuild the solution.

Comment: This was my problem.  There was a Folder in the View folde with the same name.  Hope someone don't loose as much time as I did...

Answer (score 3):

I right clicked and removed folder. Then Clicked upper the folder I wanted to create project in and created project. In the Location section I opened the File explorer and the file I had deleted still appeared -> deleted it from here and then went ahead.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by actually adding a file and then deleting it again.

Answer (score 0):

The project file was unloaded in visual studio 2017

[image]

The easiest way is to copy your project folder and paste different repository then open your project in visual studio then after run the project, it should work. 
for example
(D:--------->E:[here i mentioned repository these things])

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2017 v 15.9.12 ... I ran into this problem, but with no actual folder conflict. In my case, I had solution folder named NewOrder, and I was trying  to create a child project with the same name, but encountered the above error. I tried closing and reopening the solution (didn't restart VS so not sure if that would have made a difference) but here's what worked for me.

- renamed solution folder
- created my project. At this point, I got a strange error about not being able to locate the .net standard 2.0... so then I *did* restart VS, which fixed that problem
- renamed the folder back

Now everything works fine. I restarted VS again just for good measure and all works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, when trying to add a new project to a solution, even though a project with the same name had been removed from  the solution in visual studio (2019), I had to open file explorer and delete the folder for the removed project.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a tab open with the file name, closing it solved the issue for me

Answer (score -2):

Click on Show All Files Menu in Solution Explorer and See That file in Controller, Views and Model Folder and delete that from there also

Comment: please read [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to learn how to write a good asnwer

Answer (score -4):

You need to give attention if adding a file automatically add other files/folders..for example if I added a controller which automatically add folder with controller name in views..I couldn't add controller `.cs` file until I deleted folder with controller name from views.

Comment: This is a poorly worded question, please fix your formatting, grammar and intent. Please read the SO guidelines before posting.