# Visual Studio 2012: Can't add new item to project

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am trying to add a new item (class) to my project but I when try to do this, I initially get this warning:

[image]

Then I keep getting this error saying that the class already exists (although it doesnt) whenever I try to add a new class

[image]

What should I do to fix this ?

Answer (score 4):

Although the class isn't shown in Visual Studio as part of the project, the file still exists in the folder. In solution explorer, click the icon at the top to "Show All Files", then the file should appear in solution explorer, you can right click and select include in project.

Comment: The file does not exists. I am pretty sure. I get the error whatever name I give to the file.

Comment: In which case maybe this answer can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402950/a-file-or-folder-with-the-name-already-exists-visual-studio-2012

Comment: Ok, I excluded the test project in my solution and I can now add items. So I guess the warning is the underlying issue

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread just adding some info.

If this issue appears try to download the latest update for Visual Studio 2012, should be update 4.