# VS2017 renaming projects - the folder already contains an item named

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I am reorganizing numerous small solutions/projects into one solution in Visual Studio 2017 but I keep getting error messages like:

> The folder already contains an item named 'Staging'

Followed by:

> Exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' was
>   thrown

The projects are all in individual folders in a folder called `Packages` with the project folders named like:

- Staging.Finance
- Staging.HR
- Staging.SharePoint

There is no folder called Staging in the Packages folder and there are no files called Staging in the folder for the project I am trying to rename. The project file name is currently `Finance-SSIS` which I am trying to rename to `Staging.Finance`.

There is a project called Staging in my solution but this is in a different folder from these projects.

I can rename the project files outside of Visual Studio but want to understand why I'm getting this error.

Comment: Not sure how to repro this, might be specific to web projects.  But do beware that Windows permit folders to have an extension as well.  Users rarely do this intentionally, but you did by accident.  A folder named "Staging.Finance" has a folder named "Staging" with the extension ".Finance".  Which hopefully makes the error message meaningful.

Comment: That could be caused by a 3rd party extension/addin loaded in the Visual Studio environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Upon searching I came across these three solutions:

1. Try Restarting Visual Studio.
2. Open Solution Explorer there is an icon that looks like a many
   Pages [image] which is the `Show All
   Files`. Once clicked, one is able to see the hidden, to the visual
   studio project, the folder that was causing this error. (Look for
   the folder in the View section.). After I deleted the unwanted
   folder, and Rebuild Project, You should be able to Create the
   controller which will create the view automatically
3. A project can exist in a solution in only one location. To correct this error: 
   To show hidden Solution Folders, select the solution or a Solution Folder that contains a hidden Solution Folder and then on the Project menu, select Unhide Folders.

**Credits for solution 1 & 2: [See original answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402950/a-file-or-folder-with-the-name-already-exists-visual-studio)**

**Credits for solution 3: [See original post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e742hce.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to search in main projects file content about 'Staging' . For example take a look at solution file (with .sln extension) content and search about 'Staging', I hope you will find it there!