# How do I get LINQ To SQL to work in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2022

I have just updated to Visual Studio 2022 and I cannot get "Add ... New Item ... LINQ to SQL Classes" to work like it does in Visual Studio 2017. I have just tested this for VS 2017 on both a C# and a VB project and in both instances it works perfectly. The dbml file is created with a whole lot of references and I can drag and drop tables to the dbml after adding a database connection. When I try the same thing using VS 2022 it doesn't work for C#, nor for VB. The error message in the VB case (same for the C# case) is:

"A file with name 'TestConnectVB.dbml.layout' already exists. Please give a unique name to the item you are adding, or delete the existing item first".

The error message makes no sense on the face of it as I consciously created a new project and the first thing I did after that was to add a new LINQ to SQL Classes item with a new name (ie. one I hadn't used before), so it certainly wasn't pre-existing as the error message would seem to indicate.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kind of sounds like a hidden file is conflicting somehow.  Have you seen this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402950/a-file-or-folder-with-the-name-already-exists-visual-studio

Comment: Thanks Timothy. Very messy situation. I’ve only very recently installed VS 2022 so I think I’m going to Uninstall and ReInstall and see where I land after that. Cheers.

Comment: @rah did you ever figure this one out? struggling with same issue now

Comment: Unfortunately not. I ended up either using VS 2017 or not using DataContext in VS 2022.

Answer (score 4):

if you want to use the LINQ in VS 2022. you can install LINQ  tools on VS;
see this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M_3K0pcsMdA

I hope this answer helps you

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem with the mysterious "file already exists" message. My new dbml file was created however. What confused me however is that it is utterly useless since all the auto generated code references System.Data.Linq namespaces and it seems that .NET 6 doesn't have these and I couldn't nuget them.

I created another project in .Net (Framework) 4.6.2 and there it worked flawlessly just like in older versions of VS.

You will loose the cross platform possibility using this framework.